# How to loop data in RowDataPacket

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

How to loop data in RowDataPacket.

This problem happen because in addonis QueryBuild not return same value

as lucid models

If I use lucid models every work fine

```
const emp =  await EMP.all();
for(let i in emp.rows) {
      const data = emp.rows[i]

}
```

After I  using querybuilder I do something like this

```
const emp =  await Database
                    .table('emp');



for(let i in emp.RowDataPacket) {
      console.log('s')
      const data = emp.RowDataPacket[i]
      const emp =  await emp_sell.query()
                                  .where('emp_id',data.id);
    }
```

It's not even display 's'

Comment: you should `await Database.select('*').from('emp')`

Comment: @guijob it's same . The data return RowDataPacket . but I don't know how to fecth data in controller

Comment: oh ok, so I think you ended up with a RowDataPacket[] witch is not iterable. As a workaround you could `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emp)` to transform into js array then iterate over it

Comment: thanks, Now I can use  
emp.forEach(function(data) {
      console.log(data.id);
    });

Comment: can you add this into the answer ? I'll mark @guijob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When making this query `await Database.table('emp');`, you ended with an `RowDataPacket` objects, which is an object not iterable, as a workaround you could parse it to an array as:

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emp))`

Further reading [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1330).